# Read and write file with windows-1252

Tags: java, encoding, windows-1252

I'm trying to write a file containing some German characters to disk and read it using `Windows-1252` encoding. I don't understand why, but my output is like this:

```
<title>Wï¿½hrend und im Anschluss an die Exkursion stehen Ihnen die Ansprechpartner fï¿½r O-Tï¿½ne</title>

<p>Die Themen im ï¿½berblick</p>
```

Any thoughts?
Here is my code. You'll need spring-core and commons-io to run it.

```
private static void write(String fileName, Charset charset) throws IOException {
    String html = "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">" +
                  "<head>" +
                  "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=windows-1252\">" +
                  "<title>Während und im Anschluss an die Exkursion stehen Ihnen die Ansprechpartner für O-Töne</title>" +
                  "</head>" +
                  "<body>" +
                  "<p>Die Themen im Überblick</p>" +
                  "</body>" +
                  "</html>";

    byte[] bytes = html.getBytes(charset);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset);
    IOUtils.write(bytes, writer);
    writer.close();
    outputStream.close();
}

private static void read(String file, Charset windowsCharset) throws IOException {
    ClassPathResource pathResource = new ClassPathResource(file);
    String string = IOUtils.toString(pathResource.getInputStream(), windowsCharset);
    System.out.println(string);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Charset windowsCharset = Charset.forName("windows-1252");
    String file = "test.txt";
    write(file, windowsCharset);
    read(file, windowsCharset);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your write method is wrong. You are using a *writer* to write *bytes*. A writer should be used for writing characters or strings.

You already encoded the string into bytes with the line

```
byte[] bytes = html.getBytes(charset);
```

These bytes can simply be written into an output stream:

```
IOUtils.write(bytes, outputStream);
```

This makes the writer unnecessary (remove it) and you will now get the correct output.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. My write method is:
`byte[] bytes = html.getBytes(charset);
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
        IOUtils.write(bytes, output);
        output.close();
}`

Comment: I tested it and got the correct output from your read method!

Comment: You're right, it works. It was a IDE issue that my output file was not copied in the target directory and on the class path I had the old file.

Answer (score 0):

First ensure that the compiler and editor use the same encoding.
This can be checked trying the (ugly) `\uXXXX` escaping:

```
während
w\u00E4hrend
```

Then

```
    "<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset="
    + charset.name() + "' />" +

    byte[] bytes = html.getBytes(charset);
    Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), bytes);
```

Ahh, check that the file is in Windows-1252 too. A programmer's editor like NotePad++ or JEdit allows to play with encodings.